# Google Column Chart - outside didn't work

Tags: charts, google-visualization

What am I doing wrong?
I want to have in 1975 above the column, not on it.

```
[https://codepen.io/Serek/pen/QprYzP][1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option would be to set the max value (`viewWindow.max`) on the v-axis...

```
vAxis: {
  title: 'Amount',
  viewWindow: {
    max: vAxisMax
  }
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Q1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Q2');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Q3');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Q4');

  data.addRow(['2016', 500, 100, 1200, 1000]);
  data.addRow(['2016', 500, 100, 1975, 1000]);
  data.addRow(['2016', 500, 100, 1200, 1000]);
  data.addRow(['2016', 500, 100, 1200, 1000]);

  // find v-axis max value
  var vAxisMax = null;
  for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    var range = data.getColumnRange(i);
    vAxisMax = vAxisMax || Math.ceil(range.max / 1000) * 1000;
    vAxisMax = Math.max(vAxisMax, Math.ceil(range.max / 1000) * 1000);
  }
  // add buffer for annotation
  vAxisMax += 400;

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      top: 12,
      bottom: 24,
      left: 72
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    colors: ['#9427E0'],
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Amount',
      viewWindow: {
        max: vAxisMax
      }
    },
    bar: {
      groupWidth: '90%'
    },
    annotations: {
      style: 'point',
      alwaysOutside: true
    },
    width: 1100,
    height: 300
  };

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([
    0,
    1, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
    2, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
    3, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 3, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
    4, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 4, type: "string", role: "annotation" }
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!
It's that I need :)

Answer (score 0):

Charts seems to be auto-sizing the vertical axis to leave enough room for the tallest bar, but not for the annotation above it, even though you specified `alwaysOutside: true`.

One solution would be to set the vertical ticks explicitly.
This makes Charts leave more room at the top, and then it fits the annotation above it. Here's a version of the code you linked that adds these "ticks":

```
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Q1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Q2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Q3');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Q4');

    data.addRow(['2016', 500, 100, 1200, 1000]);
    data.addRow(['2016', 500, 100, 1975, 1000]);
    data.addRow(['2016', 500, 100, 1200, 1000]);
    data.addRow(['2016', 500, 100, 1200, 1000]);

    var options = {
        'legend': { position: 'none' },
        'colors': ['#9427E0'],
        'vAxis': {title: 'Amount',
                 // The addition:
                 // Set the largest tick bigger than the largest datum
                 ticks: [500,1000,1500,2000,2500]}, 
        'bar': {
        groupWidth: '90%'
        },
        'annotations': {
            style: 'point',
            alwaysOutside: true
        },
        'width':1100,
        'height':300};

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([
        0,
        1, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 1, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
        2, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 2, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
        3, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 3, type: "string", role: "annotation" },
        4, { calc: "stringify", sourceColumn: 4, type: "string", role: "annotation" }
        ]);


    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```